# Showing the Hausdorff metric inherits completeness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $K(X)$ denote the set of all compact subsets of $X$. Then $(K(X), d_H)$ is a metric space, where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff metric.

How can I show that if $X$ if complete, that $K(X)$ is complete?

My try: Start with an arbitrary Cauchy Sequence $\{K_n\}$ in $X$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d_H(K_n,K_m) < \epsilon$. It has been suggested to me to let $K = \{x : x = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \text{ with } x_n \in K_n\}$, and to show that $K_n \to K$. By the triangle inequality $d(K_n,K) \leq d(K_n,K_m) + d(K_m,K_N) + d(K_N,K).$

How to show that $d(K_N,K)$ can be bounded by $\epsilon$?

Comment: [Here](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/SeniorProject_KatieBarich.pdf) you can find a proof (pag. 21, but you'll need some lemmata before that).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2493757/hausdorff-distance-prove-that-if-e-d-is-complete-then-mathcalke-m